# Svelte reactive statement with a variable fron onMount

Tags: scope, svelte, reactive, sveltekit

I'm trying to style the currently active tab of my web project with the class "active". To target my tab elements I am using

```
    onMount(() => {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll(".topnav a");
});
```

I am then using a reactive statement to style the appropriate element like this

```
    $: {
    links.forEach((link) => {
        if (link.getAttribute("id") === $page.url.pathname) {
            link.classList.add("active");
        } else {
            link.classList.remove("active");
        }
    });
}
```

However, I have no way of sharing the `links` variable to my reactive statement. I also tried putting `document.querySelectorAll` inside my reactive statement (not using onMount at all), which worked flawlessly until i reloaded the page. What is the conventional approach to this?

Comment: Is the navigation not in Svelte? Because in Svelte components one should generally not need to use `querySelector` or the like to access DOM.

Comment: Have a look at the [`class:` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name) to conditionally apply a class in Svelte

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare the variable outside of `onMount` so it is in scope of the reactive statement. E.g.

```js
let links = null;

onMount(() => {
    links = ...;
);

$: if (links != null) {
    links.forEach((link) => {
});
```

(As [Bob Fanger noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72164209/546730), querying the DOM is *not* recommended and usually not necessary at all.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `document.querySelectorAll` is *not* idiomatic Svelte.

Changing class (or other attributes) use the template syntax:

```html
<a class:active={link.id === $page.url.pathname}>
  {link.label}
</a>
```

If you really need access to the DOM api's Svelte has [bind:this](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-this)   or [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) to get access to specific elements.